# using regexp on raw binary data

Tags: javascript, regex, binary-data

I'm embedding JavaScript in my C++ app (via V8) and I get some raw binary data which I want to pass to JavaScript. Now, in the JavaScript, I plan to do some regular expressions on the data.

When using just the standard JavaScript `String` object for my data, everything is quite straight-forward. However, as far as I understand it, it uses an UTF16 representation and expects the data to be valid Unicode. But I have arbitrary data (might contain `'\0'` and other raw data - although it is just text for the most part).

How should I handle this? I searched a bit around and maybe `ArrayBuffer` or something like this is the object I need to store my raw data. However, I didn't found how to do the usual regular expression methods on that object. (Basically I need `RegExp.test` and `RegExp.exec`).

---

I just checked out the Node.js code and it seems as if they support binary data and just put it into a string via `v8::String::NewFromOneByte`. See [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/string_bytes.cc) and [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/util-inl.h). So that would answer my question (i.e., I can just use `String`), wouldn't it? Any downsides?

(I still don't see why my question is bad. Please explain the downvote.)

Comment: So you want to do regex searching on binary data?

Comment: @jfriend00: Yes. I'm not sure exactly what JavaScript object to use to hold the binary data and also not if I can use standard JS regexp on it. I'm asking basically for advice, what to do with these requirements. I'm new to JavaScript.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, can you give an advice about how to make my question more clear? I'm not sure what is unclear about it.

Comment: Javascript isn't designed to do what you are trying to do.  Javascript does regular expression searching on strings.  Strings are UTF-8 encoded, not pure binary data.  I don't know what happens if you put binary data into a string and try it.  You'd have to see what happens and probably need to test in multiple browsers to know you were safe and that it does what you want it to do.

Comment: Things like `ArrayBuffer` are meant for binary data.  As best I know, you can't directly do a regex search on an ArrayBuffer (not supported in IE9 or below).

Comment: @jfriend00: I'm developing an app, so I can decide myself on the JavaScript implementation. I'm using V8 currently. But that's what I want to know with my question: What are my options, what happens if I put binary data into a string, etc.

Comment: As best I know, Javascript isn't designed to do what you want to do and thus there isn't a body of knowledge out there that you can tap into.  If you want to try to use it that way, set up some simple experiments to see what happens and whether it's workable for you with a particular JS engine.

Comment: What parts of JavaScripts design make it bad for what I'm trying to do? Also, why is my question bad? Isn't it interesting to know whether this works or good solutions of how to make this work?

Comment: I didn't say your question was bad (and I didn't downvote it).  I just said that in Javascript, regular expressions operate on strings and strings are UTF-8 encoded values, not pure binary.  If you want to try to use javascript regular expressions outside those design boundaries, you will have to test and find out what works and what doesn't work.  Simple as that.

Comment: I just checked out the Node.js code and it seems as if they support binary data and just put it into a string via `v8::String::NewFromOneByte`. See [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/string_bytes.cc) and [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/util-inl.h). So that would answer my question, wouldn't it? Any downsides? I still don't see why my question is bad.

Comment: Albert - you can submit your own answer and then accept it.  That is the proper procedure for when you discover your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

From all my current tests, it seems like it works just as expected with normal `String`.

You can even specify that in JavaScript directly, e.g.

```
var s = "\x00\x01\x02\x03"
```

and regular expressions on that string work like expected.

On the C++ side, if you want to get your binary data into a JS String object:

```
v8::Local<v8::String> jsBinary(const uint8_t* data, uint32_t len) {
    assert(int(len) >= 0);
    return String::NewFromOneByte(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, String::kNormalString, len);
}
```